# Performing arithmetic on list 'int' element

Tags: python, list

I am trying to run a code that will find the second element of a list inside a list and perform arithmetic on that piece of code, but upon trying to run said code (given below)

```
data_set_10 = [['A', 0, 0, 'E'], ['A', 0, 1, 'N'], ['A', 2, 2, 'S'], ['A', 2, 3, 'W'], 
           ['B', 0, 3, 'E'], ['B', 0, 2, 'W'], ['B', 5, 2, 'N'],
           ['C', 1, 0, 'N'], ['C', 3, 2, 'E'],
           ['D', 3, 0, 'W']]
def draw_icons(data_set):
    for group in data_set:
        for item in group[1]:
            print(-375 + (item * 75))

draw_icons(data_set_10)
```

I get the error

> File "C:/Users/Chris/Downloads/test_draw_icons.py", line 9, in draw_icons
>       for item in group[1]:
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Which is obviously something to do with the part of the code

```
for item in group[1]
```

What should I do to get the program to perform arithmetic on the item in the list? I'll give an example of the outputs im looking for:

```
-375
-375
-225
-225
```

and so on according to the second element of each list inside a list.

Comment: You don't need the third for loop.

Comment: `[-375 + (item * 75) for li in data_set_10 for item in li if isinstance(item,int)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each group is a list of 4 items, by already using `group[1]`, you are selecting the second item in `group`, which is an `int` so there is nothing to iterate over. I think this is the behaviour you are looking for

```
def draw_icons(data_set):
    for group in data_set:
        item = group[1]:
        print(-375 + (item * 75))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, as someone who is relatively new to python, it has clarified a bit of list logic to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in group[1]:
```

`group[1]` is your `int`. You're trying to *iterate over* an `int`. This obviously doesn't work.

You just want:

```
for group in data_set:
    print(-375 + (group[1] * 75))
```

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do to get the program to perform arithmetic on the item
>   in the list?

Just remove that line and replace with `item = group[1]` and reindent accordingly such that your code would look like

```
def draw_icons(data_set):
    for group in data_set:
        item = group[1]
        print(-375 + (item * 75))
```

Alternatively, you can transpose your 2D list such that a simple subscript would return the second column of elements

```
for item in zip(*data_set_10)[1]:
    print(-375 + (item * 75))
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just so simple as follows:

```
data_set_10 = [['A', 0, 0, 'E'], ['A', 0, 1, 'N'], ['A', 2, 2, 'S'], ['A', 2, 3, 'W'], 
       ['B', 0, 3, 'E'], ['B', 0, 2, 'W'], ['B', 5, 2, 'N'],
       ['C', 1, 0, 'N'], ['C', 3, 2, 'E'],
       ['D', 3, 0, 'W']]

def draw_icons(data_set):
    for group in data_set:
        print(-375+(group[1]*75))

draw_icons(data_set_10)
```

The output we get is:

```
-375
-375
-225
-225
-375
-375
0
-300
-150
-150
```